# Despite hreflang tags accessing example.nl redirects to the English site, not the Dutch

Tags: seo, google-search-console, google-search, html5

In my website I have contents in both English and Dutch. Here are my hreflang links:

```
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.example.com/en/" hreflang="en-us" />
    <link rel="alternate" href="https://www.example.com/nl/" hreflang="nl-us" />
    <link rel="alternate" href="https://www.example.com/nl/" hreflang="en-nl" />
    <link rel="alternate" href="https://www.example.com/nl/" hreflang="nl-nl" />
    <link rel="alternate" href="https://www.example.com/en/" hreflang="en" />
    <link rel="alternate" href="https://www.example.com/nl/" hreflang="nl" />
    <link rel="alternate" href="https://www.example.com/en/" hreflang="x-default" />
```

But when I access website from `example.nl` it will redirect to `https://www.example.com/en/` instead of `https://www.example.com/nl/`  What's the actual issue?

**Note**:
My client doesn't allow to access the Google Search Console, so I can't see if there are errors there?

Comment: Hreflang tags don't control redirects.   It is likely that there are *.htaccess* rules that are causing the redirects.

Comment: So how can i solve the issue??

Comment: You need to figure out how the example.nl domain is hosted.   Once you figure that out, you can look at the configuration there.

Comment: Where is the configuration

Comment: It depends on the hosting.  If it is redirected through a redirect service like from your domain registrar, then there is a web interface for it.   It could be in cPanel if you have that.   It could be in .htaccess, or even in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

**Hraflangs** are only there to indicate Search Engines that there is alternative language version of that particular page. 
In this way, you are suggesting Search Engines to show pages on SERP based on language of users browser.

On the other hand, it seems like you are having redirect issues (**.nl >>> .com instead of .nl >>> .com/nl**). If there are particular URL that keeps bugging you, use Redirect-checker to detect what kind of redirection there is.

If possible, ask administrator to deliver you full list of website redirections, or just crawl website and detect redirections by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

- You inform:

  > In my website I have contents in both English and Dutch

  And I see that there are only two versions: English
  `https://www.example.com/en/` and Dutch `https://www.example.com/nl/`
  . So I recommend that you simplify your meta hreflang - leave only
  **en** and **nl**.
- According to the blog **[Google Webmaster Central Blog "Introducing "x-default hreflang" for international landing pages"](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2013/04/x-default-hreflang-for-international-pages.html)**:

> The new x-default hreflang attribute value signals to our algorithms that this page doesn’t target any specific language or locale and is the default page when no other page is better suited.

Thus, in the meta tags you specify, you report that the web page `https://www.example.com/en/` suitable for both the English version and the Dutch version.

- Apply for **English version**:

`<link rel="alternate"
   href="https://www.example.com/en/" hreflang="x-default" />`

+
   `<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.example.com/nl/"
   hreflang="nl" />`

- Apply for **Dutch  version**:

`<link rel="alternate"
   href="https://www.example.com/nl/" hreflang="x-default" />`

+
   `<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.example.com/en/"
   hreflang="en" />`

I hope this helps.